# Get/Read Value From Svelte Store

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I want to read svelte store value at any given time.  I understand subscribe method gets called when the value is updated.  I want to read store even if there is no update on store.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like any other variable, you can use it in your template(markup) with `$` in front of the store variable it is as simple as that!

App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { count } from './stores.js';
</script>

<h1>
    {$count}
</h1>
```

stores.js

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const count = writable(0);
```

Comment: I'm going to add the text 'what does $ in front of a variable mean in Svelte' so other people find this answer. There, done!

Answer (score 1):

In `.svelte` files, see @Shriji's answer. In TypeScript/JavaScript, use the `get` function

```js
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

const value = get(store);
```

Note (from the [Svelte docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#get)):

> This works by creating a subscription, reading the value, then unsubscribing. It's therefore not recommended in hot code paths.

So if you do this often, create a subscription and keep a local variable, that stores the current value:

```js
let currentValue: number = -1;

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe((value) => {
    currentValue= value;
});

// example usage, e.g. in a websocket handler:
const onmessage = async (event: MessageEvent<any>) => {
    console.debug("Current count:", currentValue);
}

// TODO: use `unsubscribe` function, if required
```